# Discovering accesskeys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility

Is there some way to discover whether a site supports `@accesskey`s, short of brute force hammering on the keyboard or searching in the markup? I can't remember even once seeing a web site advertising their `@accesskey` keyboard shortcuts (Google and Stack* use non-standard keyboard capture) for such things as navigating to the previous/next page in a sequence (every webcomic ever comes to mind). Is there some way to discover `@accesskey`s with for example an unobtrusive Firefox extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `@accesskey` syntax, but You can use this Userstyle to make access keys defined as HTML attributes visible in Firefox, Chrome, and Opera.

http://userstyles.org/styles/10407/show-accesskeys

There isn't really any general way to reveal access keys defined using Javascript keypress listeners since the system doesn't know what's going to happen until the Javascript is actually being run.

Comment: Just added the code from it to `PROFILE_FOLDER/chrome/userContent.css` and restarted Firefox. Works perfect!